# Can a Cisco 1760 save to flash on an 1841

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

I've recently gotten a home lab started to start studying for the CCNA that consists of a few catalyst switches, 3 1760s and a single 1841. I've been messing around with saving configurations on a flash drive from the 1841. Is is possible for a 1760 to access the flash drive's file system on an 1841 and save to it? If so, what changes would I have to make to either or both devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have one router directly access the file system on a different router, but you could send a file from one router to the other with something like TFTP, and receive it on the other router using the same protocol, and save it to the local file system. Cisco routers support multiple transfer protocols.

Something like this:

R1 (sending router):

```
R1(config)#tftp-server nvram://startup-config
```

R2 (receiving router):

```
R2#copy tftp: flash:
```

[Copying From One Router to Another](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/2500-series-routers/15092-copyimage.html#copying_one_router)

Comment: btw, tftp doesn't work like that. I'll have to check if IOS actually allows inbound tftp writes.

Comment: Which one seems wrong to you?

Comment: You cannot start tftp from one router and catch it from the other. A tftp client requires a tftp server. In your example, 1.2 *must* have a tftpd on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I have sent files from a TFTP client to a router. I don't have two routers to test this with right now.

Comment: The tftp server in IOS only supports read requests. So, you can `copy tftp flash`, but not `copy flash tftp` where the tftp host is another Cisco IOS device. scp works -- albeit slow. rcp might also work, but that's a basket of insecure.

Comment: Also of note, tftp has no security of it's own. So your tftp-server entry should carry an ACL to limit what can fetch the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

(Not in the manner you may be expecting.)

You could enable the tftp server -- and/or scp server -- and use that as the url for your copies. In that respect, it's no different than sending them to any other machine/file server.

(scp) `ip scp server enable`

[update] the IOS tftp-server is for reading files, it doesn't support writing.